# add object properties to formData in vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I tryng add my prop.obj into my formData with spread like this:

```
    watch(
        () => fileRefs.value,
        () => {
            bandeiraAtt.value  ={...props.bandeiraSelected, ...fileRefs.value}
            formData.append('file', {...bandeiraAtt.value})
        },
        { deep: true }
    );
```

but, i received empty obj in my req payload.
and try with for in, and result is the same.

context: i needed sent to my backend 4 photos and someones text fields. this my object with my images(works ok):

```
    const fileRefs = ref({
        imgDestaque: <File | null>(null),
        imgBandeira: <File | null>(null),
        imgModal: <File | null>(null),
        fundoBg: <File | null>(null),
    })
```

and my req, i use fetch instance:
  `const res = await Api.post('bandeira/createOrUpdate' , formData)`
i expected push my obj in the formData, or, show me best practices to do this

Comment: `FormData` instances don't serialise to the console. If you want to debug the values, use your debugger

Comment: `FormData` values must be strings or Blobs, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append#parameters. Any object you pass will be stringified to `"[object Object]"`

Comment: i resolve with form html events, and vue event @submit and enctype multipart.